# Vanishing of some Ext groups of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

We call a coherent sheaf 'of pure support' if it has no subsheaves with support of smaller dimension.

Now, let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, $F$ and $G$ coherent sheaves of pure support on $X$.

Is it true that $Ext^i(F,G)=0$ if $2\le n ={\rm dim \ supp}G- {\rm dim \ supp}F$ ?

This is related to the similar question [Some questions on vanishing of Ext sheaves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159487/some-questions-on-vanishing-of-ext-sheaves), where we have inequality in the latter equation, but we don't have the 'pure support' hypothesis.

Thank you very much.

Comment: That is not true.  It is not even true for a regular local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ with residue field $k$.  Using the Koszul complex (or Ischebeck's theorem, etc.), $\text{Ext}^i_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R)$ is zero except for $i =\text{dim}(R)$, in which case it equals $R/\mathfrak{m}$.  On the other hand, for every $i$, $\text{Ext}^i_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R/\mathfrak{m})$ is the dual $k$-vector space of the $i^{\text{th}}$ exterior power of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$.  Thus, also $\text{Ext}^{i+1}_R(R/\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}) = \text{Ext}^i_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R/\mathfrak{m})$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 5):

I am posting my comment as an answer.  Perhaps the result that you are looking for is Ischebeck's Theorem.

**Ischebeck's Theorem.**  For finitely generated modules $F$ and $G$ over a Noetherian local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$, $\text{Ext}_R^i(F,G)$ is the zero module for all $i < \text{depth}(G)-\text{dim}(\text{supp}(F))$.

Thus, for instance, if $G$ is a Cohen-Macaulay module of $\text{depth}(G)=\text{dim}(\text{supp}(G)) = d$, then it is true that $\text{Ext}^i_R(F,G)$ is the zero module for $i< \text{dim}(\text{supp}(G))-\text{dim}(\text{supp}(F))$.  However, this can easily fail if $G$ is a module with small depth.  For instance, if $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a Noetherian local ring of depth $d\geq 2$, then for $i < d$, $\text{Ext}^i_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R)$ is the zero module.  Moreover, if $R$ is <del>Gorenstein</del> regular, then $\text{Ext}^d_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R)\to \text{Ext}^d_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R/\mathfrak{m})$ is injective.  Thus, using the long exact sequence of Ext modules associated to the short exact sequence, $$\Sigma: \ \ \ \ \ 0\to \mathfrak{m} \to R \to R/\mathfrak{m} \to 0,$$ it follows that the connecting map $$\delta_\Sigma^i:\text{Ext}^i_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R/\mathfrak{m}) \to \text{Ext}^{i+1}_R(R/\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}),$$ is an isomorphism for $i\leq d-2$, resp. for $i\leq d-1$ if $R$ is <del>Gorenstein</del> regular. (**Edit.** In fact, even in the nonregular case, $\delta_\Sigma^{d-1}$ is injective, so that $\text{Ext}^d_R(R/\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m})$ is nonzero whenever $\text{Ext}^{d-1}_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R/\mathfrak{m})$ is nonzero.)

If $R$ is a regular local ring of dimension $d$, then each $R$-module $\text{Ext}^i_R(R/\mathfrak{m},R/\mathfrak{m})$ is a vector space over $R/\mathfrak{m}$ of dimension $\binom{d}{i}$.  So, in this case, for every $i$ with $1\leq j \leq d$, $\text{Ext}_R^j(R/\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m})$ is nonzero.  In particular, the depth of $\mathfrak{m}$ equals $1$.

Presumably the reason for the hypothesis that $2\leq i$ is the evident nonzero element of $\text{Ext}^1_R(R/\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m})$ coming from the non-split short exact sequence $\Sigma$.  However, even in the "best" case of regular local rings, $\text{Ext}_R^j(R/\mathfrak{m},G)$ can easily be nonzero for $R$-modules $G$ that have support of large dimension yet have small depth.